# Vuejs HighCharts - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined" Error

Tags: vue.js, charts, highcharts, organization

I am using below dependencies to use HighChart organization chart in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "highcharts": "^7.0.1",
    "highcharts-vue": "^1.0.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
```

This is how I am injecting this in main.js

```
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import organizationInit from 'highcharts/modules/organization'

organizationInit(Highcharts)

Vue.use(HighchartsVue)
```

This is how I am using in Organization.vue page

```
<template>
  <highcharts class="organization" :constructor-type="'organization'" :options="orgOptions"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      orgOptions: {
        rangeSelector: {
          selected: 1
        },
        title: {
          text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        series:[{
        type: 'organization',
        name: 'Highsoft',
        keys: ['from', 'to'],
        data: [
            ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
            ['Board', 'CEO'],
            ['CEO', 'CTO'],
            ['CEO', 'CPO'],
            ['CEO', 'CSO'],
            ['CEO', 'CMO'],
            ['CEO', 'HR'],
            ['CTO', 'Product'],
            ['CTO', 'Web'],
            ['CSO', 'Sales'],
            ['CMO', 'Market']
        ],
        levels: [{...
```

But I am getting below error:

[image]

I tried several ways but this is last form. What should I do?

Comment: Organization chart requires also a sankey.js module. It seems that it is missed in your code. If this wouldn't help, please reproduce your code on some online editor.

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: It seems to be the same as this: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue/issues/123

Comment: @skirtle I did not recognize this issue's existence. Adding sankey is resolved my issue also. Thank you all